# export: `-A': not a valid identifier on Mac Terminal start

Tags: terminal, osx, macintosh

I have a weird problem when starting the Terminal on my Mac. I get the following output whenever I start it, but have no idea what `` export: `-A': not a valid identifier `` means.

```
Last login: Tue Feb 14 08:49:23 on console
-bash: export: `-A': not a valid identifier
MacBook-Pro:~ username$
```

Edit: Here is the content of the .bash_profile

```
export PATH="/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH"ssh-add -A
```

Any ideas what causes this and how I could fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
export PATH="/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH"ssh-add -A
```

is likely wrong. I can imagine it's supposed to be

```
export PATH="/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH"
ssh-add -A
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.bash_profile` has an error in it that's getting run when you start a new shell.

Comment: Saying that there's an error is really just a re-statement of the problem; an Answer should resolve the problem, not restate it.